# Post data with ajax to java servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets, post

First of all, pardon me if my english is bad. I'm having some problems with sending data to my ExportServlet with ajax.

**ExportServlet.java**

```
public class ExportServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6715605810229670146L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String fileName = req.getParameter("filename");

    //Create ZIP file
    try {
        res.setContentType("applicatin/zip");
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(res.getOutputStream());

        //Create TXT file
        zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(fileName + ".txt"));
        zos.write(getOutputData());
        zos.closeEntry();

        zos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private byte[] getOutputData() {
    byte[] result = null;
    String tmp = "Text file content";
    result = tmp.getBytes();
    return result;
}
}
```

The java code above works absolutely perfect.

Then I have my ajax code that sends data to my ExportServlet (I have used filename for an example):

```
//Post data to ExportServlet
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/export.zip',
            data: "filename = myFile",
            success:function(data){alert(data);},
            error:function(){alert('error');}
        });
```

The problem is that when the ajax function is triggered I get an error callback. I also have a link to download the ZIP file generated by ExportServlet:

```
<a href="/export.zip">Download file</a>
```

And indeed, when I click the link I get ZIP file with "null.txt" in it. How can I fix this?

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: You only have implemented the `doGet` for your servlet, not the `doPost`.

Comment: One more thing: you can't trigger file download using ajax. Imagine a malicious server that start downloading files and applications into your computer without your permission.

Comment: Yes I know, the problem is that when I change doGet to doPost I can't download the file anymore (ahref won't work). 

I don't want to trigger file download, I just want to trigger ExportServlet to create a file with ajax. Then when you click on the download file link, It will download the created file.

Comment: Please read my second comment.

Comment: C'mon buddy, in ajax you request the data with `POST` method, while you just implemented the `GET` method in servlet. so you own me a coffee :D

Comment: @user2511414 again: you **cannot** download a file using ajax.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Okay Okay buddy, I didn't say doenload the file, I said wrong method triggered, and yes, he may set the session using ajax request and redirect the page by javascript to the page which provides the file :), now you own me a coffee too :)

Comment: @user2511414 I ow nothing to you =\. You trigger a file download with a POST and do not need ajax nor javascript for this. Geez.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza wow, about the ajax I don't know what business is behind this call! maybe it's for request or trigger something before file download, who knows?! and maybe you have better solution, but I don't give up about my coffee :D, haha

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="downloadFile();">Download file</a>
<div style="display: none;">
   <iframe id="downloadFileFrame"></iframe>
</div>


function downloadFile() {
    $('#downloadFileFrame').attr('src','/export.zip?filename=myFile');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the link, the ajax code will not be called so the filename parameter will not be included in the request to the servlet. The servlet will execute with filename = null. That is the actual result you got.

To fix this, I think you have to call the ajax code at the first time the page loaded so that your servlet can create a file and place it on the server. Then you have to pass filename parameter in your link such as:

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com/downloadFile?filename=myFile">Download file</a>
```

The downloadFile servlet will look for file named myFile.txt which was created at the first time your page loaded with ajax called, and give you the file in response.

Comment: *I am not sure what your servlet do* It is triggering a file download (read the question again and comments on it). And one more time: you **cannot** trigger file download using ajax.

Comment: I have changed my reply. Thank you